# Downloading HTML files without opening a browser

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a URL which I don't want to open up in a browser. The servlet which my URL points to is able to download the JPEG image of the rendered HTML document using html2canvas library based on specific params.

How can I download the HTML as JPEG even without rendering the HTML on the client side. Is that possible?

Comment: Set the appropriate HTTP headers - I believe it's `Content-Disposition: attachment; some_filename.extension`

Comment: @lan: Can you please provide me a example?

Comment: It depends on your server, and what your actual question is. Your title is simpler than your main content's question "How can I download the HTML as JPEG". I can "answer" your title's question...about converting it to a JPEG would either be a lot more work or impossible (at least the way you describe it)

Comment: Yeah..you are correct. I tried Rahul's answer below and it triggers my browser to download the HTML file automatically. However, the HTML is downloaded without rendering my stuff inside the HTML. I want to render it in some sort of virtual browser on my server and then download it at the client side.

Comment: You could do it in an `<iframe>` then (if I understand correctly). Have a normal page and append an `<iframe>` with the `src` attribute as your file's, and it should automatically bring up a download dialog (as long as you have the headers set)

Comment: Thanks lan. I dnt want to use iframe because of its performance issues. However, I will try to use something like phantom.js. If you have any idea about, please share your thoughts.